# How to print out newline ASCII?

Tags: c, ascii

Trying to print out the decimal equivalent `\n` (newline) with below code. When it is executed I press enter and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> but nothing is printed on screen. I expect 10 to be printed. What am I missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char ch;

    while ((ch = getchar() != EOF))
    {
        if (ch == '\n')
        {
            printf("\\n=%d\n", ch);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while ((ch = getchar() != EOF))
```

This assigns the value `getchar() != EOF` to `ch`. You probably meant to write:

```
while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
```

P.S. `ch` should be of type `int`, as `EOF` is a negative value which `char` isn't required to be able to represent (`char` might be `unsigned`) and thus on some systems, you might never see this condition evaluate false if `ch` is (erroneously) `char` (thus you'd have an infinite loop on such systems).

Comment: about the `EOF` problem: It's actually even worse, if you **have** signed `char`, `-1` could be a valid character, which will then be misinterpreted as `EOF`.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I agree that the loop is faulty either way, but the failure mode when `char` is `unsigned` is much more likely to be noticed or seen as troublesome. In a similar tone that people suggest avoiding `scanf`, I'd suggest avoiding `getchar` for this reason... you can get much clearer, easy to understand code by using `fread` instead, i.e. `while (fread(&ch, 1, 1, stdin))`...

Comment: @Applik Welcome to StackOverflow. The upvote and tick feature is how we thank people, here... If this answer solves your problem, accept it as your solution by clicking the "tick". If it doesn't, let me know... but I think it solves your problem. You're welcome. :)

Comment: @Applik C has plenty of pitfalls, but if we avoid what allows them, C becomes useless... buffer overflows, so we shouldn't use arrays or `strcpy` or `memcpy` or anything that can cause those... right? Race conditions, so we should avoid threads entirely... `goto`, so we should avoid that too... we should avoid all of these tools that *can be used to write poor code* even though they *can also be used in reasonable ways*... We need to go back to caveman days, with rock and fire because knives are too dangerous... in fact, fire is too dangerous too... rocks... hmmm, life has its pitfalls...